# Android Automotive OS emulator including Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-automotive

October 21 Google announced

> Today, we’re announcing that developers can download an updated Android Automotive OS emulator system image that includes the
> [Google Play Store](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-automotive-os-updates-for.html?m=1).

I cannot find this emulator, I have both the Polestar 2 image  Revision 1 and the Android 9.0 (Automotive) Revision 3 but none of them a the google service.

Do you know where I can find this emulator image?